# How to find element type in XPath

Tags: xml, xpath, schema

I have an XML which has an attached schema, is there a way to identify if an element is of a complex type defined in the attached schema ?

Ex:

Schema

```
<element name="Cosmin" type="CosminType" />
<element name="Cosmin2" type="CosminType" />
```

XML

```
<parent>
    <cosmin>bla</cosmin>
</parent>
```

I want to make an `XPath` that will identify all elements of type `CosminType`, be it `Cosmin` or `Cosmin2`.

I was wondering if there is something like:

```
//parent/*[@type="CosminType"]
```

I tried `@xsi:type` and it doesn't work. If nothing works I will try to find something unique inside `CosminType` and get the `parent`, which in my case will be `Cosmin` and `Cosmin2`. But this is not a pretty solution.

Comment: Have you looked at the `instance of` XPath operator? http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-instance-of

Answer (score 0):

First you need the element name, because this one is need to be searched into the attached XSD:

```
/parent/cosmin/name()
```

This one should be used searching in the attached XSD, something like:

```
document('attached xsd')//element[@name=/parent/cosmin/name()]/@type
```

Hope this helps

Comment: hey thanks for quick answer, but would prefer not to search in the xsd. isn't there some pseudo-attributes that even though they are not physically in the XML they can be deduced from the attached schema ?

Comment: Not that I know off or have ever used